# In linux, how to find whether CMOS battery is working or not?

Tags: linux, battery, c++, cmos

I want to programatically determine whether CMOS battery is working or not. In my C++ program on linux I want to connect to internet and update system time if CMOS battery is not present or not working.

Comment: What Mainboard do you use? What Linux Distri you use?

Comment: @kockiren linux distro is ubuntu. my program should work independent of Mainboard. Actually i want my program to work on regular desktop as well as beaglebone.

Comment: I think it isnt possible to check the capacity of cmos battery if you're BIOS dosent give you some tools you can use on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I believe BIOSes set a bit in the CMOS RAM somewhere if a checksum error occurred.  But this is specific to each manufacturer of motherboard.

One thing that may work ...

- Dump the CMOS RAM on shutdown - `dd if=/dev/nvram of=cmos_ram.bin` will probably do it.
- Retrieve it on power up.
- Compare with saved file from last shutdown.  If there is a mismatch, CMOS was changed or corrupted.  So do system time update.

Honestly due to the drifiting and inaccuracy of many CMOS clocks you should update the system time on each boot anyway.

Comment: I think ur answer only works on the system started immediately after CMOS battery failure.

Answer (score 1):

KISS!

use NTP to correct the time always (ntpdate and then the ntpd).

This way you have the correct time always. 
This is what the computer without CMOS or internal clock do it.

There is no need to build any other program (they exist already) nor check the CMOS (it's good to have it, but not required)

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible, but likely won't be cross-platform (since you want to use it both on a PC and a BeagleBone, which have vastly different hardware).

Run ntp, which will always keep your time correct regardless of the battery's status.